# Interpret the visualization of k-mean clusters

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, k-means

Following [my posted data here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158342/data-preparation-for-cluster-analysis), I conducted a k-mean clustering analysis. 
I refereed to [this post: How to produce a pretty plot of the results of k-means cluster analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-to-produce-a-pretty-plot-of-the-results-of-k-means-cluster-analysis) for the clusters visualization

```
# Read and Sort Input Data
mydata <- read.csv(file="three_county_6_25.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",") # read input data
mydata2 <- scale(mydata)  # Normalize the data

# Determine number of clusters
wssplot(mydata2)
set.seed(1234)
nc <- NbClust(mydata2, min.nc=2, max.nc=15, method="kmeans")
table(nc$Best.n[1,])

# Do K-means clustering
set.seed(1234)
fit.km <- kmeans(mydata2, centers = 3, nstart=25)

 # Visualize the clusters
 # Fig 1
 plotcluster(mydata2, fit.km$cluster)
 # Fig 2
 clusplot(mydata2, fit.km$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE,labels=2, lines=0)
 # Fig 3
 with(mydata, pairs(mydata2, col=c(1:3)[fit.km$cluster]))
```

The NbClust indicates 2 clusters:
[image]

Here are the visualization of clusters:[image]

I am not sure how to interpret the clusters visualization result.
**1) The 1st cluster plot is doing "Centroid Plot against 1st 2 discriminant functions". It seemed the clusters showed three groups.
2) The 2nd cluster plot "vary parameters for most readable graph" (referred from [Quick-R: Cluster Analysis](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html)).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data contains **correlations**.

k-means cannot handle correlations, and failed badly.

Either split your data manually based on the visualization (the left looks reasonable), or use a different algorithm capable of handling linear elongated clusters.

Comment: Do you think if I do PCA on the data, then do k-means on the PCs, will that solve the correlation problems? I saw a post indicated this solution: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92985/when-plotting-clustering-results-in-the-pca-coordinates-does-one-do-pca-or-clus/92987#92987

Comment: Sometimes. Sometimes not. Visualize again, and check if A) the results look much better in the visualization, and B) the plot exhibits a real elbow. No elbow in the plot usually indicates that kmeans didn't work.

Comment: Also, could you guide me to understand why the correlation will fail k-means? I did a quick search, but don't have the fortune to find the exact answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=k+mean+correlation

Comment: Correlation roughly means scaling one axis, but not another. K-means is *very* sensitive to rescaling axes differently.